# How can I move uncommitted work on wrong Git branch?

Tags: git

The other day I created a new project branch `f-testing-docs` and before I switched to it I fixed a typo on the current `master` branch. The issue is that I guess I forgot to swap to the new branch before doing the new work.

So now I have 3 files that are not staged for commit, and 3 that are untracked completely.

How can I move these changes seemlessly into `f-testing-docs` and off of this master branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be to run

```
git stash
git checkout f-testing-docs
git stash pop
```

`stash` will back up the files. `stash pop` will allow you to solve any conflicts before transferring to the new branch. If there are no conflicts, the stash will be dropped automatically. If there are, the stash will hang around as a backup until you run

```
git stash drop
```